# Aspx blocks my form

Tags: html, asp.net, forms

I am working on client's webpage which is build in aspx and silverlight.

I have following form:

```
<form method="post" action="https://app.freshmail.com//pl/actions/subscribe/"><br>
      <input type="hidden" name="subscribers_list_hash" value="here mu value"><br>
      <label for="freshmail_email">Email2</label><br><br>
      <input type="text" id="freshmail_email" name="freshmail_email"> <br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Wyślij"><br>
</form>
```

So when I add this code through client's cms into webpage the form shows up but it does not execute the form. I have created simple html just to check if the form works and it works, means that when I add email address and hit submit it takes me to specified website to confirm that addresss was added to the list. So there is something with aspx that blocks it? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The problem might be <form> tag? two <form> tags cant be nested. So when you add the, form from web page then <form> tag comes under one form tag, thats's the problem

Comment: @Piyush I am not sure if that's the case. Here is the link with not working form [link1](http://portal.kurs.vulcan.pl/jst/kargowa1/CMS/newsletter.aspx)  [link with working form](http://piotr.silesius.pl/newsletter.html)

Comment: I have tried , it takes me to `https://app.freshmail.com//pl/actions/subscribe/` i.e. form-action page, so i think it should be working like this only.